# Jquery Bootstrap FormValidator Reset without clean input data

Tags: jquery, jquery-form-validator

I want to reset the validations of my form without to clean the data (form.reset()). I am using FormValidator(http://www.formvalidator.net/).

This validator use the method reset of the form but I don't want clean the input data, I just want remove the red borders and the error messages.

http://www.formvalidator.net/#configuration_setup

`// Reset form using jQuery
$('#container form').get(0).reset();`

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I COPIED the reset function of the form-validator.

```
//CIRO : Its a copy of the JS without the element errorMessageCustom    
var configReset = {
        ignore: [], // Names of inputs not to be validated even though node attribute containing the validation rules tells us to
        errorElementClass: 'error', // Class that will be put on elements which value is invalid
        borderColorOnError: '#b94a48', // Border color of elements which value is invalid, empty string to not change border color
        errorMessageClass: 'form-error', // class name of div containing error messages when validation fails
        validationRuleAttribute: 'data-validation', // name of the attribute holding the validation rules
        validationErrorMsgAttribute: 'data-validation-error-msg', // define custom err msg inline with element
        errorMessagePosition: 'element', // Can be either "top" or "element" or "custom"
        errorMessageTemplate: {
          container: '<div class="{errorMessageClass} alert alert-danger">{messages}</div>',
          messages: '<strong>{errorTitle}</strong><ul>{fields}</ul>',
          field: '<li>{msg}</li>'
        },        
        scrollToTopOnError: true,
        dateFormat: 'yyyy-mm-dd',
        addValidClassOnAll: false, // whether or not to apply class="valid" even if the input wasn't validated
        decimalSeparator: '.',
        inputParentClassOnError: 'has-error', // twitter-bootstrap default class name
        inputParentClassOnSuccess: 'has-success', // twitter-bootstrap default class name
        validateHiddenInputs: false // whether or not hidden inputs should be validated
      }
//you can search the code with the text "reset.validation" at the "jquery.form-validator.js"
function resetValidation(idForm){
        $elems1 = $("#"+idForm).find('.' + 'error' + ',.valid');        
        $("#"+idForm).find('.' + 'error' + '.alert').remove();
        $.formUtils.errorDialogs.removeErrorStyling($elems1, configReset);
    }
```

This code was emergency and can be improved